# Can I use eval to instantiate a dynamic backbone view like this?

Tags: javascript, oop, backbone.js, backbone-views

I know I should stay away from eval, but I have replaced this piece of code:

```
switch (nr) {
    case 1:
        return new Frontier.OnlineAdviceBundle.View.PanelStep1({ el: wizardEl.find('.panel-wrapper.classname1'), model: this });
    case 2:
        return new Frontier.OnlineAdviceBundle.View.PanelStep2({ el: wizardEl.find('.panel-wrapper.classname2'), model: this });
    case 3:
        return new Frontier.OnlineAdviceBundle.View.PanelStep3({ el: wizardEl.find('.panel-wrapper.classname3'), model: this });
}
```

with:

```
nr = parseInt(nr, 10);
var className = this.get('stepClassNames')[nr];

return eval("new Frontier.OnlineAdviceBundle.View.PanelStep" + nr + "({ el: wizardEl.find('.panel-wrapper." + className + "'), model: this });");
```

What is your opinion on this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

No need for eval. Just use bracket instead of dot accessor for View, do:

```
return new Frontier.OnlineAdviceBundle.View['PanelStep' + nr]({ el: wizardEl.find('.panel-wrapper.classname'+nr), model: this });
```